# php var value contains quotes

Tags: php, variables, attributes, echo, quotes

So... I have a mysql_fetch_array and I'm running into an issue when some of the mysql data contains single or double quotes. This is the dumbed down version of my code:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td onclick='edit_form(\"" . $row['item'] . "\");'>" . $row['item'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }
```

The edit_form() function is used to send the value of the current item back to the value of the input in the form so the user can then easily edit their entry and then sends an UPDATE command to mysql along with the proper primary key id (which I left out because of irrelevancy). The only issue I have is if a user puts single or double quotes into the form then it messes up the onclick attribute. Please help!! I am pretty new to php and can't figure this out. I've messed around with htmlentites() and html_entity_decode() but am still getting no where. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) on `$row['item']` before inserting it in your document.

So your "dumbed-down" code should be:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)) { 
    $item = htmlspecialchars($row['item']);
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td onclick='edit_form(\"" . $item . "\");'>" . $item;
    echo "</td></tr>"; 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work with or without the \" inside the edit_form() function. I think it's because the echo is writing it as html and the browser is interpreting the entities... but when I use json_encode() the only thing that breaks it now are single quotes! It takes care of double quotes just fine. Praise the Lord! Thanks for your reply though!

Answer (score 0):

I advise using json_encode. That way you don't have to worry about special cases htmlspecialchars might miss (such as newlines).

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td onclick='edit_form(" . json_encode($row['item'], JSON_HEX_APOS) . ");'>" . $row['item'];
    echo "</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now it only breaks when a single quote is used... still need to figure that out... You were very helpful!

Comment: Forget about that gotcha. I added the JSON_HEX_APOS flag in to take care of single quotes.

Comment: I haven't tried that. I just figured out what works for me though! $item = json_encode($row_sean1['item']); $item = str_replace("'","&#39;",$item); and i just use $row_sean['item'] for the val of the <td>. So the <td> shows the raw val from the sql query but when the onclick attr is written to the page (via while loop) it encodes the "special" characters and any single quotes are converted to entity so it won't mess up any of the quotes used for echo and the onclick attr. The only thing I don't understand is why it is displayed correctly when $item becomes the value of <input> in the <form> :\

Answer (score 0):

Try the below line instead of the original in your code and see if it works:

```
echo "<td onclick='edit_form(\"" . str_replace('"',"&quote;",$row['item']) . "\");\">" . $row['item'];
```

And where you would like to display the $item field, just replace it in reverse if you get "e; instead of ' " '. For example:

```
$qoute_free= str_replace('&quote','"',$passed_value);
```

If you are using it in javascript, the function can be as below:

```
function edit_form(passed_value)
{
  new_value=passed_value.replace(/&quote;/g,'"');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just putting the values back into my `<form>` (when they click on a `<td>`) and when they hit SUBMIT it directs the data to a different .php file that uses a MySQL UPDATE instead of an INSERT. I finally found some code that works!

- `$list` is a `mysql_query` I ran at the top of the document
- `$item` is the title of one of my columns in MySQL

  ```
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($list)){
      $item = json_encode($row['item']);
      $item = str_replace("'","&#39;",$item);
      echo "<td onclick='edit_form(" . $item . ");'>" . $row['item'] . "</td>";
  }
  ```

Now it display's correctly in the `<form>` when `<td>` is clicked (by jQuery `input.val($item)`) and it shows up in the table correctly via `$row['item']`. I don't really understand exactly how it's working (how the encode is making it work) but I am glad it is. Crazyness!!!! Thanks for responding! and thanks for your effort!!